# Using XPath to parse (SOAP-based) XML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

I am receiving the following XML from a SOAP-based Web service via an AJAX call.

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <ActivityId
            CorrelationId="d2ba6844-ec96-4ddc-a3aa-36c8bdd2daeb"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">
            8c74da56-65c1-4f50-9dc6-547dc9b208a6
            </ActivityId>
        </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <MyResponse
            xmlns="http://foo.example.com/">
            <MyResult
                xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <Bar>
                    1ab6cd3a6499
                    </Bar>
                </MyResult>
            </MyResponse>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

I would like to use XPath on the (JavaScript-based) client to parse the XML to find the value for `Bar`.

I am able to use XPath to parse this XML on iOS with KissXML. I first add a namespace called `baz` to the root element with value `"http://foo.example.com/"`, and then I can call `nodesForXPath:error:` with an XPath expression like `"/s:Envelope/s:Body/baz:MyResponse/baz:MyResult/baz:Bar"`.

Despite reading the [Introduction to using XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) on MDN, I can't figure out how to correctly call the `evaluate` function.

**How do I parse this XML in JavaScript?**

(I do not have any dependencies on any external libraries, e.g. jQuery, so I'd prefer if my solution did not require me to add any libraries.)

Comment: What's that with adding a "baz" namespace?  You don't have to create a namespace declaration for that.

Comment: Adding a `baz` namespace allows me to prefix `MyResponse`, `MyResult` and `Bar` in my XPath statement, since they are all in a default namespace declared in the `MyResponse` element.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a jsfiddle to show you how to use the javascript evaluate function to obtain the Bar element's value using xPath:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/uL7rA/

The code to achieve this is here:

```
var bar = document.evaluate('//MyResponse/MyResult/Bar', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null );

alert( bar.singleNodeValue.textContent );
```

Comment: I don't want to grab just any `Bar`. I want to be sure I am getting that exact one.

Comment: I've modified the answer to get the Bar element which is within the MyResponse element. Is this now specific enough?

Comment: `'//MyResponse/MyResult/Bar'` will match the first such sequence it finds, which may not be inside the SOAP body inside the SOAP envelope; e.g. if you added `<MyResponse><MyResult><Bar>badvalue</Bar></MyResult></MyResponse>` inside the SOAP header. Part of the reason I'm using XPath like this is to perform some basic data validation.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one `<Bar>` element, it might be much easier to user `.querySelector()` instead of XPath, like

```
doc.querySelector('Bar')
```

Comment: There may not be one `Bar`. The `Bar` I need to get must be inside the SOAP body which is inside the SOAP envelope; no other `Bar` should match.